# Getting multiple errors when converting mt HTTP to Observable

Tags: angular, typescript

I am running to some issues to convert my HTTP requests to an observable. In my angular App i have a service called API Service ho handles all requests to back end's and then for each component i have a service which then makes calls to this service to get or update date on the API. As part of my migration i run into a few things..

1. is i get the

> Expected 0 type arguments, but got 1

, based on my reasearch some cases are due to people using http vs httpClient, i use the later

2. The other is when i return the data i get this

> Type 'Observable<HttpEvent>' is not assignable to type
> 'Observable'.   Type 'HttpEvent' is not
> assignable to type 'GithubApi'.
> Type 'HttpSentEvent' is missing the following properties from type 'GithubApi': items, total_count

[Stackblitz Sample](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-table-01-fxd3eg?file=src/app/httprequest.ts)

The code actually still runs as long as i don't enable IVY. Hopefully someone can point me in the right direction of what i am missing here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So there are 2 problems here:

1. Your `get` method doesn't accept a type which you can easily fix by allowing it: `get<T>`
2. Your `get` method doesn't return a proper type depending on this type. I casted it to `Observable<any>` for the examples sake but you should ofc do something meaningful there.

I suggest you to take a look at the Angular code and see how they do it to get inspiration.

"Fixed" stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-table-01-y3zdng?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapi.service.ts

Code block related to it:

```
  get<T>(config: {
    endpoint: string;
    useAuthUrl?: boolean;
    params?: any;
    reqOpts?: any;
  }): Observable<GithubApi>
```

Comment: Thanks, i get the <T> part which solves the 1 but expected 0. As for the Observe<any> what does it actually observe her ? It because if i change it from any to GithubAPI i get the error again ?

Comment: That error is thrown because you're changing the default config params in your `initRequestOptionsAndParams` method. If you remove that config you'll see that the error will be gone when you typecast any to GithubAPI

Comment: What I mean is your config object returned from the `initRequestOptionsAndParams` method is not `HttpParams` which angular expects. If you update the method return type like this `private static initRequestOptionsAndParams(config: any): HttpParams`. You'll see what's missing.

Comment: @SamS87 I updated my stackblitz. I changed the way you supply the params to the http.get. Now the typecasting works.

Comment: After taking a closer look yur code breaks my old code, since when you change from params?: any to params?: HttpParams before i passwed in my params like sort order or offset via the params object which now longer is possible since they are not part of HttpParams

Comment: How does it break? Can you demo it on the stackblitz?

Comment: Ok here is the revised [stackblitz sample]https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-table-01-jxd8ae?file=src/app/api.service.ts, , the issue is that if i define params? as HttpParams it fails. but doing an any it works. As the initRequestOptionsAndParams sets the actual HttpParams i think that should be fine. The issue is if i set the Observable<GithubApi> i get this error 'Observable<HttpEvent<GithubApi>>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<GithubApi>'.

Comment: ok what do you want to provide as the 2nd parameter of the http.get? If it's the http params then you might want to do it like this: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-table-01-tq6j4h?file=src/app/api.service.ts

Comment: Ok, i tried it and yes it gets rid of the <HttpEvent> issue but it creates a new issue. if i use the code with your change it creates an url output of **/user/getall?params=offset=0%26rowcount=1** vs without that **/user/getall?offset=0&rowcount=1** the first one does not work as the API does not expect an params=

Comment: Sure sure, I gave that as an example; I actually don't know what your api expects. As long as you follow angulars interface expectations it should be ok. Otherwise you need to typecast it. Your `config.reqOpts` isn't what angular expects in that line. So you either need to follow the interface or use something like as any